# How to center float=left textboxes and buttons inside a float=left div

Tags: html, css

I have a TextBox and button with both styled `float=left` because I need these 2 side by side and `display:inline-block` not solve this problem because it will put some space or not aligning vertically or works in Mozilla but not in Chrome.

The `div` that have the textbox and button also have `float=left`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="CabecalhoArea">

    <div style="float: left; width:180px;">
        bla bla
    </div>

    <div style="float: left; margin-top:10px; width:calc(100% - 650px); text-align:center;">
        <!-- search-->
            <asp:TextBox CssClass="search_text" runat="server" placeholder="search here"/> 
            <asp:Button CssClass="search_button" runat="server"  />
        <!-- //search-->
    </div>

    <div style="float: left; width:310px;">
       bla bla
    </div>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#CabecalhoArea{
    position: fixed;
    left:110px;
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#ecf0f1;
}

.search_text{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 42px;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: #666666;
    outline: none;
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search_button{
    border: 0 none;
    background: #fff url(search.png) center no-repeat;
    width: 50px; 
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 42px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:-4px;
}
```

I try: `text-align: center;`

I try: replace `float=left` by `display:inline-block;`

but no success...

any suggestions?

Sorry my english.
Joao

Comment: Read about CSS [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Flexbox is really the best solution, but, I believe the idea is to align everything, side by side.

```css
#CabecalhoArea{
  background: dodgerblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="CabecalhoArea">

    <div>
        bla bla
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <!-- search-->
            <input type="text" class="search_text" runat="server" placeholder="search here"/> 
            <button class="search_button" runat="server">Button</button>
        <!-- //search-->
    </div>

    <div>
       bla bla
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox:

```css
#CabecalhoArea{
  background: dodgerblue;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="CabecalhoArea">

    <div>
        bla bla
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <!-- search-->
            <input type="text" class="search_text" runat="server" placeholder="search here"/> 
            <button class="search_button" runat="server">Button</button>
        <!-- //search-->
    </div>

    <div>
       bla bla
    </div>


</div>
```